# How to add quantity input to product list page to category page in OpenCart?

Tags: customization, opencart-3

I wanted to let the customer **choose quantity to add into cart directly on the product list page** (category, search etc). Here is the way I solved this problem on OC3. Please be advised that I'm not an expert and a **Vqmod modification would be much better** than my "hardcoded" solution.

Anyway, here is it:

1. Edit catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.twig
2. Add following code before  {% for product in products %}

```
    <script>
                 function inviacart(id) {
                 quant= $('#input-quantity-'+id).val();
             cart.add(id,quant);    
                 }
                 </script>
```

3. Add following code before div class="button-group">

```
     <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="input-quantity">Qt.</label>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="{{ product.minimum }}" size="2" id="input-quantity-{{ product.product_id }}" class="form-control" />
    </div>
```

4. replace

```
    <button type="button" onclick="cart.add('{{ product.product_id }}', '{{ product.minimum }}');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">{{ button_cart }}</span></button>
```

with

```
    <button type="button" onclick="inviacart('{{ product.product_id }}');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">{{ button_cart }}</span></button>
```

5. repeat the same for search page or other product list pages.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

Some told me there is this extension doing the same much better than my solution:

https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=31229&filter_member=letscms